# How can I write a selenium script with c# and automate it to find the downtime and uptime of a website?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I am an automated tester in selenium and c# (not the greatest developer) but I have been tasked to find out the uptime and downtime of the website.  Now I guess this script would be run everyday because my scripts run on a build server at 00.05am every night.  So my question is how do I get the numbers?  I have found a pretty good post on here which is similar but what I don't understand is, how to get the availability/uptime over a period of time? How did he get 86400)/100) * 97.91m? Check out the code guys

```
 CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

 DateTime first = DateTime.ParseExact("20.04.2015", "dd.MM.yyyy", provider);
 DateTime last = DateTime.ParseExact("26.04.2015", "dd.MM.yyyy", provider);

 TimeSpan time = last - first;

 decimal secondsUptime = ((time.Days * 86400)/100) * 97.91m;  //97.91 is the uptime calculated above for the time period. 

 // The problem is how to get this?

 decimal secondsDowntime = ?
```

So the guy had problems getting the downtime and the posts answer was this:

```
decimal PercentDownTime = 100 - PercentUpTime;
decimal SecondsUpTime = (time.Seconds / 100) * PercentUpTime;
decimal SecondsDownTime = (time.Seconds / 100) * PercentDownTime;
```

Comment: So...website has zero monitoring?  `selenium` is not a solid monitoring option IMO.

Comment: Yes orde would a tool better? or a c# script?

Comment: What is considered downtime? How do you plan to determine the downtime? What is uptime? If you hit the main page of the site and get a response, is that up? What if some services aren't working but you can't access them from the home page? There are a LOT of questions you haven't answered but you need to think about. Selenium is not a good tool to do this. First you should ask your dev or manager if there are already tools in place that record the up/down time of the server/site and use those first.

Comment: JeffC uptime means the application is operational, generally this is a high percentage 90% downtime is when its not operational.  Yes if you get a response this means its operational.

Answer (score 0):

This is ideally a monitoring problem. You may not need selenium for this. Few ways could be

1. See if you can capture the web server logs and grep the logs to see the uptime and downtime
2. You can write a tool which keeps polling the website and record if it is sending you the right response or not. Based on the response you can decide the uptime and downtime.
3. Ask your admin team to install a monitoring system in the webserver which will have much more wider soltuion for many problem.